# Duda sobre como usar la api de noticias de NY times en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Tengo este script:

```javascript
$.getJSON('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all.json?api-key=YFmbKu0o5dGhWU8R3HPUOwHSq3fovjA3', function(data) {
    // JSON result in `data` variable
});
function setup() {
    
    noCanvas();
    loadJSON(url, gotData);
    
}
    
function gotData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    
}
```

El problema es que no pone nada en la consola, ni muestra ningun error. Si no soluciono esto, el proyecto que estoy haciendo y todo su trabajo van a ser en vano.

Comment: El `console.log()` tiene que ir dentro de la funcion `getJSON()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es lo siguiente :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all.json?api-key=YFmbKu0o5dGhWU8R3HPUOwHSq3fovjA3', function(data) {
            //los datos de la respuesta están en la variable data
            console.log(data)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pero tienes que tratar de formulas preguntas correctamente.

Comment: gracias, te voy a hacer caso ;)